# Unity3D cloned object doews not show up on the game tab but I can see all the clones on the scene tab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public GameObject arrow;
public float launchForce;
public Transform shotPoint;                  
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    shoot();
}   
private void shoot()
{
    GameObject newArrow = Instantiate(arrow, shotPoint.position, shotPoint.rotation);
    newArrow.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = transform.right * launchForce;
 }
```

When I click the left button the program clones the arrows and I can see them in scene tab but I can't see them in the game tab.

How I can show arrows in the game tab ?

That is **2D** and the arrow object have the `Rigidbody2D Box Collider`.

Comment: Maybe they are present, but as the children of some other object. Check the small triangles on the left of each objects to unroll object hierarchy. Also, if their lifespan is short for some reason, you may just not have enough time to spot them.

Comment: I checked lifespan. i think problem is rendering but i coudn't anythink

Answer (score 0):

if you see them in the scene tab, the arrows must have been created as well. i would guess that the positions are not set correctly. Have you ever checked this?

Comment: yes ı have a platfrom archer sitting on it and i can count arrows on sceen tab everything awesome

Comment: Check **z** position, if **z** position is lower than camera's that rendering, objects won't be visible. If that's not the case either, check layer of object. If prefab on the layer that shouldn't be rendered by camera, that can cause the problem.

Comment: @SeleCtRa thx you are true when i fixed cloned arrows z everythink ok